# Failed to resolve import axios vue vite

Tags: vue.js, axios

i am creating the vue js project along with vite i ran into the problem while i am running

```
[plugin:vite:import-analysis] Failed to resolve import "axios" from "src\components\Student.vue". Does the file exist?
```

what i tried so far i attached below.
i installed npm i axios but why getting this error.and import the **import axios from 'axios';**
as well

```
 <script>
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import axios from 'axios';
 
     Vue.use(axios)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you forget to install axios. Try `npm install axios --save`